# Let $R$ be a ring of finite characteristic, then $ch(R)＝ch(R/m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to find a DVR **which has positive characteristic** and mixed character($ch(R)$ and $ch(R/m)$ is different.)

But I couldn't find such a example. And I conjectured the following.

Let $R$ be a ring of nonzero finite characteristic, then I guess $ch(R)＝ch(R/m)$.

Is the last claim true?
If it is not true, I want counter example, and that is what I was looking for.

P.S
This is obvious typo from context, $chR$ is positive.

Comment: The characteristic of a ring is always finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most typical example is the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers (where $p$ is a prime). It has characteristic $0$, and its residue field is $\mathbb{F}_p$, which has characteristic $p$. You can also take the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ as an example.

If a DVR $R$ has positive characteristic, though, it must be a prime $p$ since $R$ is an integral domain. Since there are ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_p \to R \to R/\mathfrak{m}$, it follows that $p$ is the characteristic of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ as well.

Comment: Sorry you already answered my question. Thank you so much.